# How can we print the current webpage to a pdf file using php

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

Can any one help me out with some suggestions...

In my application i need to convert the current web page that contains graphs and some tables with petty some images to a PDF files...
Actually this is a report of a certain scenario...

Thanks in advance...

~Ur Raviraja

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: Also see [List of HTML to PDF converters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you might be looking for [this](http://pdfmyurl.com/).

```
<a href="http://pdfmyurl.com?url=www.mypage.com">download My page as pdf</a>
```

Also this question should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910243/how-to-convert-an-html-to-pdf-in-php-using-fpdf-lib-1-6